# Error in installing aria2c in python while installing Windows VM

Tags: python, virtual-machine, homebrew

I'm trying to install Windows VM in accordance with the instructions https://sugary-selenium-eb9.notion.site/Power-BI-installation-guide-for-Mac-ed07be30d6b94cf2ad9325dddd38d9d3

I have a Mac with an Intel chip.

I Enter the following commands:

- `chmod +x uup_download_macos.sh`
- `./uup_download_macos.sh`

And I get this error:

```
aria2c does not seem to be installed
Check the readme.unix.md for details
```

I can't find aria2c on official python site.

How can I solve it?

I tried

```
pip install aria2c
brew tap aria2c
```

Answer (score 6):

You may need to install Homebrew (via Terminal):

1. Enter `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
   then press **enter/return**
2. Run `echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile`
3. Run `brew install aria2 cabextract wimlib cdrtools sidneys/homebrew/chntpw`

Here's a [reference](https://macappstore.org/aria2/) up until #2

Comment: The OP already seems to have tried `brew` though the formatting of the question obscured this. Are you saying `brew install` should be preferred over `brew tap`?

Comment: Worked for me. Not sure why the readme.unix.md didn't include "aria2"